# CS50P PS2 Vanity Plates How to make middle letters in str invalid

Tags: python, loops, cs50

I'm doing PS2 for CS50P and am stuck and need some help. Here are the conditions of the code:

> In Massachusetts, home to Harvard University, it’s possible to request
> a vanity license plate for your car, with your choice of letters and
> numbers instead of random ones. Among the requirements, though, are:
>
> - “All vanity plates must start with at least two letters.”
> - “… vanity plates may contain a maximum of 6 characters (letters or numbers) and
>   a minimum of 2 characters.”
> - “Numbers cannot be used in the middle of a plate; they must come at the end. For example, AAA222 would be an acceptable … vanity plate;
>   AAA22A would not be acceptable. The first number used cannot be a
>   ‘0’.”
> - “No periods, spaces, or punctuation marks are allowed.”

I have everything functioning correctly except when it has letters in the middle of the str (in my code as `s`) for example `FE43E2` should output invalid, but it's current outputting valid. How should I implement this?

Here is my current code:

`

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
def is_valid(s):
    if 2 <= len(s) <= 6 and s.isalnum():
        if s[0].isalpha() and s[1].isalpha():
            if s[-1].isdecimal():
                for char in s[2:]:
                    if char.isdecimal():
                        has_number = True
                        if char.isalpha() and has_number:
                            print("Has letters in the middle")
                            return False
                        elif char != "0":
                            print("No leading 0")
                            return True
                        else:
                            print("Leading 0")
                            return False
                else:
                    print("First two characters are letters")
                    return True
            else:
                print("Doesn't end with a number")
                return False
        else:
            print("First two characters arent letters")
            return False
    else:
        print("Length of isn't between 2 and 6 characters")
        return False
main()
```

I currently trying to say if any character is a number after the first 2 characters of s then if there is also a letter in the s to return False and therefore invalid.

Comment: Don't use nested `if` like this. Use a series of `if` conditions at the top level that check for invalid cases and immediately return `False`. Finally return `True` at the end if none of the cases fail.

Comment: Note that there are a number of posts like this on SO and you might have luck checking out for example [Vanity Plates - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76263215/vanity-plates-python). I'm not saying that your post is a duplicate, just that that post might help.

Comment: The condition `and has_number` will always be true, since you just did `has_number = True` on the previous line. That block of `if` statements shouldn't be indented inside `if char.isdecimal():`

Comment: Note, as a general bit of personal advice, I would swap stuff around to "fail fast" with guards in order to [prevent the arrowhead anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804005/how-to-prevent-the-arrowhead-anti-pattern)

Comment: You've asked us to solve a broad problem. Break it down into simple parts and post on the single part you're stuck with.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem becomes easier to solve if you use a very simple state machine rather than a deeply nested `if` statement. Something like:

```
import pytest


def is_valid(plate) -> bool:
    # vanity plates may contain a maximum of 6 characters
    # and a minimum of 2 characters
    if len(plate) < 2 or len(plate) > 6:
        return False

    state = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(plate):
        # vanity plates may contain...letters or numbers
        # No periods, spaces, or punctuation marks are allowed
        if not (c.isdecimal() or c.isalpha()):
            return False

        if state == 0:
            # All vanity plates must start with at least two letters
            if c.isdecimal():
                return False
            if i == 1:
                state = 1
        elif state == 1:
            # If we find a number, everything else needs to be numbers
            if c.isdigit():
                # First number used cannot be '0'
                if c == "0":
                    return False
                state = 2
        elif state == 2:
            # Letters after numbers is not allowed
            if c.isalpha():
                return False

    return True
```

We can add a simple test suite using [pytest](https://pytest.org) to verify that things work as expected:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "plate,valid",
    (
        ("A", False),  # Too short
        ("111111", False),  # Does not start with letters
        ("22AAAA", False),  # Does not start with letters
        ("AA..AA", False),  # Contains non-alphanumerics
        ("AA22AA", False),  # Numbers cannot be in middle
        ("AA0000", False),  # The first number used cannot be 0
        ("A22222", False),  # Must start with two letters
        ("AAAAAAA", False),  # Too long
        ("aaaaaaa", False),  # Letters must be uppercase
        ("AA", True),
        ("AA2222", True),
        ("AAAAAA", True),
    ),
)
def test_is_valid(plate, valid):
    assert is_valid(plate) == valid
```

Running these tests with `pytest -v` produces:

```
test_plates.py::test_is_valid[A-False] PASSED
test_plates.py::test_is_valid[111111-False] PASSED
test_plates.py::test_is_valid[22AAAA-False] PASSED
test_plates.py::test_is_valid[AA..AA-False] PASSED
test_plates.py::test_is_valid[AA22AA-False] PASSED
test_plates.py::test_is_valid[AA0000-False] PASSED
test_plates.py::test_is_valid[A22222-False] PASSED
test_plates.py::test_is_valid[AAAAAAA-False] PASSED
test_plates.py::test_is_valid[aaaaaaa-False] PASSED
test_plates.py::test_is_valid[AAAAAA\xd1-False] PASSED
test_plates.py::test_is_valid[AA-True] PASSED
test_plates.py::test_is_valid[AA2222-True] PASSED
test_plates.py::test_is_valid[AAAAAA-True] PASSED
```

---

I'm using `isalpha()` in the above code to test for letters. This is arguably wrong; while it's not explicit in the regulations, I suspect that:

- Letters must be upper case
- Letters must only be English letters from A-Z

As written, words like `lower`, `NIÑO`  and `SCHÖN` are valid license plates. If you'd prefer different behavior, you could replace:

```
        if not (c.isdecimal() or c.isalpha()):
            return False
```

With:

```
        if not (c.isdecimal() or c in string.ascii_uppercase):
            return False
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the [state machine answer by @larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77808266/218663) and I encourage you to review it. State machines can make very complicated flows trivial.

Since the "hints" offer suggestions of using `str` methods and slicing, let's see if we can form a simple solution using them with a simpler state machine that just tracks if we have seen a digit or not.

Note that this is not going to be anywhere near the performance of @larsks' answer as we potentially evaluate the entire string multiple times but once you understand it and how `found_a_number` works you can graduate to using `state` in their answer.

```py
def is_valid(plate):
    ## -----------------
    ## maximum of 6 characters and minimum of 2 characters
    ## -----------------
    if not (2 <= len(plate) <= 6):
        return False
    ## -----------------

    ## -----------------
    ## No periods, spaces, or punctuation marks
    ## -----------------
    if not plate.isalnum():
        return False
    ## -----------------

    ## -----------------
    ## must start with at least two letters.
    ## -----------------
    if not plate[:2].isalpha():
        return False
    ## -----------------

    ## -----------------
    ## Deal with numbers
    ## -----------------
    found_a_number = False
    for character in plate[2:]:
        ## -----------------
        ## first number used cannot be a "0"
        ## -----------------
        if character == "0" and not found_a_number:
            return False
        ## -----------------

        ## -----------------
        ## letters cannot appear after numbers
        ## -----------------
        if character.isdigit():
            found_a_number = True
        elif found_a_number:
            return False
        ## -----------------
    ## -----------------

    ## -----------------
    ## It must have been good
    ## -----------------
    return True
    ## -----------------

def test_plate(plate):
    return plate, is_valid(plate)

print(test_plate("AAA222"))
print(test_plate("FE43E2"))
```

That should give you:

```
('AAA222', True)
('FE43E2', False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying out your code, the nested "if" statements seemed to not align with the rules noted in your issue.  What seems to be required is to prompt for a license plate number, then run through a simple gauntlet of tests as noted (valid min/max length, first two characters being alphabetic, and not having embedded digits).  With that following is a refactored version of the program.

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

def is_valid(s):
    numchar = False

    if len(s) < 2 or len(s) > 6:
        print("Invalid length - less than two or greater than six")
        return False

    if not s[0].isalpha() or not s[1].isalpha():
        print("First two characters are not alpha")
        return False

    x = range(len(s))

    for n in x:
        if s[n].isdigit():  # Numeric character is encountered
            if s[n] == '0' and not numchar: # First encountered digit cannot be zero
                print("Initial digit may not be zero")
                return False
            numchar = True 
        if s[n].isalpha():  # Alpha character encountered - check to see if any previous character is digit
            if numchar:
                print("Embedded numeric characters are not allowed")
                return False

    print("Entered plate code is valid")    # If this point is reached, the plate code is valid
    return True
    
main()
```

Testing out various license plate samples, including your entry (FE43E2), appears to yield the appropriate terminal output.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Plates$ python3 License.py 
Plate: FE43E2
Embedded numeric characters are not allowed
Invalid
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Plates$ python3 License.py 
Plate: D 
Invalid length - less than two or greater than six
Invalid
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Plates$ python3 License.py 
Plate: D34444
First two characters are not alpha
Invalid
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Plates$ python3 License.py 
Plate: DDW345
Entered plate code is valid
Valid
```

And to address the other validity requirement noted in the comments, following is an additional test for the initial digit not being allowed to be zero.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Plates$ python3 License.py 
Plate: AA0234
Initial digit may not be zero
Invalid
```

The takeaway here would be that there are times where nesting of tests are required, but attempt to determine if simple serial testing will provide the required results.

Comment: You are right.  I missed that test embedded in the comments.  So, I edited my refactored code to address that omission.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<first you check the first to characters and then check the length of user's input, then you check the last character of user's input to see if it is digit or alpha, so it is  alpha you loop on the input checking if there any digits so it would return false, but if the last character is a digit you loop on the input to check if the first digit in the input and determine if it is not equal to "0" if so you add the method isalnum to exclude the unwanted characters then return true but if it equals to "0" then return false.

"it took me about to days  : )  "

def main():

```
plate = input("Plate: ").upper()
if is_valid(plate):
    print("Valid")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

def is_valid(s):

```
    if s[0:2].isalpha() and 6 >= len(s) >=2 :
        if s[-1].isalpha():
            for _ in s :
                if _.isdigit() :
                    return False
        elif s[-1].isdigit():
            for _ in s :
                if _ != "0" and _.isdigit() and s.isalnum() :
                    return True
                elif _ =="0" and _.isdigit():
                    return False       
    else:
        return False
```

main()